# IP address will not connect to same IP address

Tags: java

EDIT: This question was written by someone else in my project group. It's not very well worded, or informative, so if you've stumbled here by some accident let me know if you need any clarification etc.

The server sends the IP address through a message to the client. Our client then reads the message and displays the IP address by reading it.  I have it where it gathers the right numbers, but does not connect when back to the sent IP address. Any idea why it won't connect even with the same address? The code is given below:

```
byte IPAddr[] = Arrays.copyOfRange(message, 3, 7); //and that is equal to "0.0.0.1" 

try {    
  InetAddress IP = InetAddress.getByAddress(IPAddr);    
  Socket clientSocket = new Socket(IP, returnPort);    
  System.out.println("Connected!");    
}
```

Comment: the client and server will connect however when "localhost" or 127.0.0.1 is typed into the IP spot in Socket clientSocket = new Socket(IP, returnPort)

Answer (score 2):

The server has multiple IP addresses. For this to work, the address it gives to the client must be its *external* IP address. One example that won't work is the loopback address, 127.0.0.1, even though it's a correct IP from the server's point of view.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Unfortunately, this was a problem with our server and how its loops were structured given our problem set.

For instance, you're absolutely right that the external address is what has to be supplied. In our case, our server returned a byte array with the first byte of the IP set to zero no matter what - our local loop testing showed an IP of 0.0.0.1.

Once we fixed our conditional loops, it ended up that we had everything right. If anyone has a similar question to this and needs more clarification, feel free to reply.

Thanks again @Jack.